# Virtuemart search results point to category NOT product details page

Tags: php, search, joomla, virtuemart

Inherited old Joomla site I've upgraded since 2.5 circa 2012, now 3.6.4 with Virtuemart 3.0.16 (using PHP7.0).

Default Joomla search module results appear as:

> **[Lorem Ipsum product link]**
>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean accumsan est mi, et volutpat quam blandit a. Etiam blandit, massa ac consequat dapibus product description.

Except the hyperlink of the product title erroneously points to the product category instead of the product detail page.

I believe I have located the issue in this location: /plugins/search/virtuemart/virtuemart.php. Approx. line 223:

```
$row->virtuemart_product_id . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $row->cat_id;
```

I do not know how to change the php into the correct format to point to the product itself. I have tried to change the language from category to product id declaration but this results in mix-matched product links.

How can edit this file to make the product title link point to actual product details page and not the category?

```
<?php

/**
 *
 * A search plugin for com_search
 *
 * @author Valérie Isaksen
 * @author Samuel Mehrbrodt
 * @version $Id: authorize.php 5122 2011-12-18 22:24:49Z alatak $
 * @package VirtueMart
 * @subpackage search
 * @copyright Copyright (C) 2004-2008 soeren - All rights reserved.
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
 * VirtueMart is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
 * to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
 * is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
 * other free or open source software licenses.
 * See /administrator/components/com_virtuemart/COPYRIGHT.php for copyright notices and details.
 *
 * http://virtuemart.net
 * @modified by Jeno Kovacs --- Offlajn.com 2014 
 * @description image & price support for Universal AJAX Live Search  
 */
// no direct access
defined ('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class PlgSearchVirtuemart extends JPlugin {
    /**
     * @return array An array of search areas
     */
    function onContentSearchAreas () {
        $this->loadLanguage();
        static $areas = array(
            'virtuemart' => 'PLG_SEARCH_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCTS'
        );
        return $areas;
    }

    /**
     * Content Search method
     * The sql must return the following fields that are used in a common display
     * routine: href, title, section, created, text, browsernav
     *
     * @param string $text Target search string
     * @param string $phrase matching option, exact|any|all
     * @param string $ordering ordering option, newest|oldest|popular|alpha|category
     * @param mixed  $areas An array if the search it to be restricted to areas, null if search all
     *
     * @return array An array of database result objects
     */
    function onContentSearch ($text, $phrase = '', $ordering = '', $areas = NULL) {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        if (is_array($areas)) {
            if (!array_intersect ($areas, array_keys ($this->onContentSearchAreas()))) {
                return array();
            }
        }

        $limit = $this->params->get('search_limit', 50);
        switch($this->params->get('subtitledisplay', '1')) {
            case '1':
                $category_field = 'category_name';
                break;
            case '2':
                $category_field = 'customtitle';
                break;
        }
        $search_product_description = (bool) $this->params->get('enable_product_description_search', TRUE);
        $search_product_s_description = (bool) $this->params->get('enable_product_short_description_search', TRUE);
        $search_customfields = (bool) $this->params->get('enable_customfields', TRUE);
        $customfield_ids_condition = "";
        if ($search_customfields) {
            $value = trim($this->params->get('customfields', ""));

            // Remove all spaces
            $value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
            if (!empty($value)){
                $customfield_ids = explode(",", $value);

                // Make sure we have only integers
                foreach($customfield_ids as &$id) {
                    $id = intval($id);
                }
                // The custom field ID must be either in the list specified or NULL.
                $customfield_ids_condition = "AND cf.virtuemart_custom_id IN (" .
                    implode(',', $customfield_ids) . ")";
            }

        }

        if (!class_exists('VmConfig')) {

        // FIX THE MISSING DS ERROR ON JOOMLA 3 VM BETTER SEARCH PLUGIN : https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=125681.0
        defined('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

        require(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'components' . DS . 'com_virtuemart' . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'config.php');
        }
        VmConfig::loadConfig();

        $text = trim($text);
        if (empty($text))
            return array();

        switch ($phrase) {
            case 'exact':
                $wheres2 = array();
                // product_sku should be exact match
                $text = $db->quote("%$text%", TRUE);
                $wheres2[] = "p.product_sku LIKE $text";
                $wheres2[] = "a.product_name LIKE $text";
                $wheres2[] = "b.$category_field LIKE $text";
                if ($search_product_s_description)
                    $wheres2[] = "a.product_s_desc LIKE $text";
                if ($search_product_description)
                    $wheres2[] = "a.product_desc LIKE $text";
                if ($search_customfields)
                    $wheres2[] = "(cf.customfield_value LIKE $text $customfield_ids_condition)";
                $where = '(' . implode (') OR (', $wheres2) . ')';
                break;
            case 'all':
            case 'any':
            default:
                $words = explode (' ', $text);
                $wheres = array();
                foreach ($words as $word) {
                    $wheres2 = array();
                    // product_sku should be exact match
          $word = $db->quote("%$word%", TRUE);
                    $wheres2[] = "p.product_sku LIKE $word";                    
                    $wheres2[] = "a.product_name LIKE $word";
                    $wheres2[] = "b.$category_field LIKE $word";
                    if ($search_product_s_description)
                        $wheres2[] = "a.product_s_desc LIKE $word";
                    if ($search_product_description)
                        $wheres2[] = "a.product_desc LIKE $word";
                    if ($search_customfields)
                        $wheres2[] = "(cf.customfield_value LIKE $word $customfield_ids_condition)";

                    $wheres[] = implode (' OR ', $wheres2);
                }
                $where = '(' . implode (($phrase == 'all' ? ') AND (' : ') OR ('), $wheres) . ')';
                break;
        }
        switch($ordering) {
            case 'alpha':
                $order = 'a.product_name ASC';
                break;
            case 'category':
                $order = 'b.category_name ASC, a.product_name ASC';
                break;
            case 'popular':
                $order = 'a.product_name ASC';
                break;
            case 'newest':
                $order = 'p.created_on DESC';
                break;
            case 'oldest':
                $order = 'p.created_on ASC';
                break;
            default:
                $order = 'a.product_name ASC';
        }

        $shopper_group_condition="";
        $currentVMuser = VmModel::getModel('user')->getUser();
        $virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids = (array)$currentVMuser->shopper_groups;

        if (is_array($virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids)) {
            $sgrgroups = array();
            foreach($virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids as $virtuemart_shoppergroup_id) {
                $sgrgroups[] = 'psgr.`virtuemart_shoppergroup_id`= "' . (int)$virtuemart_shoppergroup_id . '" ';
            }
            $sgrgroups[] = 'psgr.`virtuemart_shoppergroup_id` IS NULL ';
            $shopper_group_condition = " AND ( " . implode (' OR ', $sgrgroups) . " ) ";
        }

        $uncategorized_products_condition = VmConfig::get('show_uncat_child_products') ?
            '' : ' AND b.virtuemart_category_id > 0 ';

        $query = "
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    a.product_name AS title,
                    a.product_s_desc AS text,
                    p.created_on as created,
                    p.published,
                    '2' AS browsernav,
                 (SELECT m.file_url AS path
                  FROM #__virtuemart_medias AS m
                    LEFT JOIN #__virtuemart_product_medias AS me ON m.virtuemart_media_id = me.virtuemart_media_id
                    WHERE me.virtuemart_product_id = a.virtuemart_product_id ORDER BY me.ordering ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS image,
                    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.$category_field
                        ORDER BY b.$category_field SEPARATOR ', ') as section,
                    (SELECT pc2.virtuemart_category_id
                        FROM #__virtuemart_product_categories as pc2
                        WHERE pc2.virtuemart_product_id = a.virtuemart_product_id LIMIT 1) AS cat_id
                FROM `#__virtuemart_products_" . VmConfig::$vmlang . "` AS a
                JOIN #__virtuemart_products AS p USING (`virtuemart_product_id`)
                LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_categories` AS xref
                        ON xref.`virtuemart_product_id` = a.`virtuemart_product_id`
                LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_categories_" . VmConfig::$vmlang . "` AS b
                        ON b.`virtuemart_category_id` = xref.`virtuemart_category_id`
                LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_shoppergroups` as `psgr`
                        ON (`psgr`.`virtuemart_product_id`=`a`.`virtuemart_product_id`)
                LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_product_customfields` AS cf
                        ON cf.virtuemart_product_id = a.virtuemart_product_id
                LEFT JOIN `#__virtuemart_customs` AS customs
                        ON customs.virtuemart_custom_id = cf.virtuemart_customfield_id
                WHERE
                        ($where)
                        AND p.published='1'
                        $shopper_group_condition
                        $uncategorized_products_condition
                GROUP BY xref.virtuemart_product_id
                ORDER BY $order";
        $db->setQuery($query, 0, $limit);
//echo $query; exit;
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
        if ($rows) {
            foreach ($rows as $key => $row) {
                $rows[$key]->href = 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails' .
                    // line below somehow changes search result links without changing title
                    $row->virtuemart_product_id . '&virtuemart_category_id=' . $row->cat_id;
          $rows[$key]->price = $this->getPrice($row->virtuemart_product_id);
          if($row->image != "" && (false === strpos($row->image, "stories"))) {
            $rows[$key]->image = "images/stories/virtuemart/product/".$row->image;
          }          
            }
        }
        return $rows;
    }

  function getPrice($pid) {
     if (!class_exists('CurrencyDisplay')) {
          require_once(JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'currencydisplay.php');
    }  
    $product_model = VmModel::getModel('product');
    $currency = CurrencyDisplay::getInstance();
        $product = $product_model->getProduct($pid,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,1);
        $p = str_replace("PricesalesPrice", "", $currency->createPriceDiv ('salesPrice', '', $product->prices));
    return $p;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My psuedo-solution was to import the aforementioned virtuemart.php file from a vanilla Virtuemart download that matched the version I am using.

The file extracted was found in com_virtuemart.3.0.14_ext_aio.zip: /admin/plugins/search/virtuemart/virtuemart.php.

Renamed original post php file to .bak and dropped this one in the same location. Results are now behaving like stock Joomla search (sans all custom styling).